# Sqlite/Local storage in sencha

Tags: sqlite, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch-2

In my sencha based application i want to save my pin number ,reteive the pin number & edit the pic number.The appliaction im running with phonegap using sencha touch. For doing the above operation i have gone through the links regarding SQLITE in Sencha touch.But nothing is clear ove there.Can any one please show me some effective links for local storage / SQLITE in sencha based application.Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for create local storage in sencha app using phonegap go through bellow link
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage